# c# stop eventhandler after timer stops

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, timer

How come my eventhandler never stops calling even after i stopped my timer? Is there something wrong with my code? Please help!

I've included my whole code inside, if you guys could do me some help please :)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start system
        axInRFIDCtrl1.SelectReaderFeig();
        axInRFIDCtrl1.FEInit();
        short sResult = axInRFIDCtrl1.FEOpen();
        //MessageBox.Show(sResult.ToString());

        //Start timer1
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get ID
        string strTagIds = string.Empty;
        int iState = 0;

        axInRFIDCtrl1.FESelect(ref strTagIds, ref iState);

        string[] strTagID = strTagIds.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        string strTag = strTagID[0];
        textBox1.Text = strTag;

        //Connection to datebase
        string c1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(c1);

        //Bind button
        string txt = textBox1.Text;

        string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        string strSqlStatement = string.Empty;
        strSqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM jiahe WHERE [Tag ID] = '" + txt + "'";
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSqlStatement, objConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        objAdapter.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            string strLine = string.Empty;
            string strUser = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string strTags = dr["Tag ID"].ToString();
                strUser = dr["User"].ToString();
                string strAge = dr["Age"].ToString();
                string strPhoneNumber = dr["Phone Number"].ToString();

                // prepare command string
                string selectString = @"SELECT Status FROM jiahe where [Tag ID] = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                // 1. Instantiate a new command with command text only
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, objConnection);

                // 2. Set the Connection property
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                // 3. Call ExecuteScalar to send command
                string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                cmd.Connection.Close();

                foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    //string strName = string.Empty;
                    strName = datarow["User"].ToString();

                    if (str.Length == 2 || str.Length == 0)
                    {
                        // prepare command string
                        string updateString = @"update jiahe set Status = 'OUT' where [Tag ID] = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                        // 1. Instantiate a new command with command text only
                        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(updateString, objConnection);

                        // 2. Set the Connection property
                        cmd1.Connection.Open();

                        // 3. Call ExecuteNonQuery to send command
                        str = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
                        cmd1.Connection.Close();

                        //write text file to outgoing spool
                        //TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\cygwin\var\spool\sms\outgoing\sms.txt");

                        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test.txt");
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine("To: 6592786618\n");
                            tw.WriteLine("\n");
                            tw.WriteLine("\n" + strName + @" has just left at " + DateTime.Now);
                            tw.Close();
                        }

                        MessageBox.Show(strName + " has left the house.");

                        //Start timer2
                        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                        timer2.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 30; //30 mins interval
                        timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
                        timer2.Enabled = true;
                        timer2.Start();

                        //Log to listbox
                        // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
                        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
                        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " - " + strName + " > OUT");
                        listBox1.EndUpdate();

                        //Log event to log file
                        string cs = "Minder+Finder Event Log";
                        EventLog elog = new EventLog();

                        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
                        {
                            EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, cs);
                        }

                        elog.Source = cs;
                        elog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        elog.WriteEntry(DateTime.Now + " - " + strName + " > OUT");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // prepare command string
                        string updateString = @"update jiahe set Status = 'IN' where [Tag ID] = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                        // 1. Instantiate a new command with command text only
                        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(updateString, objConnection);

                        // 2. Set the Connection property
                        cmd1.Connection.Open();

                        // 3. Call ExecuteNonQuery to send command
                        str = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
                        cmd1.Connection.Close();

                        //write text to outgoing spool
                        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test.txt");
                        //using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText("C:\cygwin\var\spool\sms\outgoing\Test.txt"));
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine("To: 6592786618\n");
                            tw.WriteLine("\n");
                            tw.WriteLine("\n" + strName + @" has just returned home at " + DateTime.Now);
                            tw.Close();
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(strName + " has returned home.");

                        //Stop timer2
                        timer2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
                        timer2.Enabled = false;
                        timer2.Stop();

                        //Log to listbox
                        // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
                        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
                        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " - " + strName + " > IN");
                        listBox1.EndUpdate();

                        //Log event to log file
                        string cs = "Minder+Finder Event Log";
                        EventLog elog = new EventLog();

                        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(cs))
                        {
                            EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, cs);
                        }

                        elog.Source = cs;
                        elog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        elog.WriteEntry(DateTime.Now + " - " + strName + " > IN");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        form3.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(strName + " has left");

        //write text file to outgoing spool
        //TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\cygwin\var\spool\sms\outgoing\sms.txt");
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Test1.txt");
        {
            tw.WriteLine("To: 6592786618\n");
            tw.WriteLine("\n");
            tw.WriteLine("\n" + strName + @" has just left at " + DateTime.Now);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something else is calling it?

Comment: "timer2.Interval = 2000; //30 mins interval" - not quite. It's 2 seconds.

Comment: What happens in between?  Are you sure you're unsubscribing from the same timer instance?

Comment: Only timer2 is calling it. I changed it to 2 seconds to test, my problem lies with the event handler. I've read other sites that say by stopping the timer, the eventhandler will still be called, so how do i stop it all?

Comment: Does timer2_Tick() re-enable the timer, perhaps? And are you confident that the code which stops the timer is actually getting executed?

Comment: Also, .Start()/.Stop() and .Enabled=true/false are the same -- use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: timer2.Interval = newTimeSpan(0,30,0).TotalMilliseconds;, will give you 30 minute interval.

Comment: Yes Ken, i'm sure the code which stops the timer gets executed, but nothing works. Thanks Joe, i've tried putting one or both but none works though. 2 seconds interval is for testing, i can't possibly wait for 30 mins for the next call.

Comment: @Jethro: Or, better yet, `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds`.

Comment: Holy cow.  Take some time to clean up timer1_Tick -- it cannot be maintainable.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to c#. What is it that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If timer2 is an instance variable, then the problem is that you're creating a local variable also called timer2 and starting that. You're then stopping the member variable timer2, not the local scope timer2. The local scope timer2 will keep firing until the garbage collector gets around to disposing it.

I'm pretty sure timer2 is an instance variable, otherwise the other references to it wouldn't compile. Also note that because you're creating the timer2 inside a loop, you're probably creating a boatload of them, and all of them happily fire away until the garbage collector puts them out of their misery.

EDIT:Here is a fairly simple example of use within a Form.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/GUIandtimer.htm

If you are simply dropping timer components onto your form design, then the initialization is written for you in the InitializeComponents method as in this example. Other than this though, I can't help much more. I think there are some structural problems in the way you are trying to use the timer. All the starting and stopping, especially with timer2 in that for loop seems like it will cause you much trouble and headache.

Comment: I kinda get you a little. How should i create the variable then?

Comment: Create the timer2 once in your constructor, or where object instances are initialized. Then every thing references that single instance.  The form plumbing may be creating it for you depending on how you've included it in your form class.

Comment: Can you see my timer1? It's weird how i managed to call Timer1_Tick eventhandler when timer1 ticks, and then "amazingly" Timer1_Tick is still called even if i comment out timer1. Why?

Comment: You're doing the same thing with timer1 as you are with timer2. You're creating a timer and assigning it to a local variable, not the object's member variable. Get rid of the timer1 creation/assignment line too.

Comment: GOT IT! I removed timer2 creation line and timer1 and timer2 both worked great. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

If you stop the timer (by calling `Stop()` or by setting `Enabled = false`), then it will not fire again. I have *never* seen a case where a stopped timer calls the event handler. If the event handler is still being called after you disable the timer, then either some other code is calling it, or something is re-enabling the timer.

Note also that if the event handler is currently executing, stopping the timer will not abort the event. It also won't prevent any pending events. Although that shouldn't be an issue with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, since its event handler always executes on the GUI thread.

Were I you, I'd inspect the code very carefully and see all the places where the timer is enabled or disabled. I suspect you'll find that there is something in your code that's re-enabling the timer.

Edit after seeing your posted code:

Likely the problem is that in your timer event handler you have the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
// code that initializes and enables timer
```

That creates a local `timer2` variable, which will be different from your `timer2` that's at form scope (I assume, since you imply that the code compiles, and you reference a `timer2` in a separate scope). You end up creating a new timer, but the code that disables the timer is referencing the form-scope `timer2`. So what's happening is that you're creating a lot of different timers, and every one of them ends up calling the same event handler.

I hope your calls to `MessageBox.Show` in the event handler are just for debugging purposes. You don't want to leave those there, because they block the UI thread and will prevent additional timer ticks until they're dismissed.

Comment: Thank you for being so clear. I've checked my codes countless times but still can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: I got it now. However, the same thing happens for timer1 where i actually comment out timer1 at Form_Load and yet timer1_Tick eventhandler is still called. Why is this so?

Comment: I got it by removing System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your stop code would be better as:

```
//Stop timer2
timer2.Stop();
timer2.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
```

As for your real question...we need to see the rest of your code to help you.

Comment: Without your RFID stuff I can't really test anything.  Also, it's not good to accept an answer as the solution, if it's not the solution.  With that said, here are some things in your code to consider as possibly the problem: 1) You're activating timer2 from inside timer1's tick, this can't be easy to follow or maintain. 2.) You're stopping timer 2 in the else block, but you're doing it after some db queries and a message box, if you know you're stopping timer2 in the else, do it at the begining of the block. 3.) Set some break points and follow through.  There is an answer here, its not magic

Answer (score -1):

This code, as written never fires the timer, because it gets prevented (in three different ways) before the time elapses.